# How do I process IQ data received from a signal analyzer

Tags: matlab

I used a signal analyzer to get IQ sample data from a blue tooth device. The IQ data received is in the form of a .MAT file and I examined the file contents and see an + ibn samples where a, b are constants, n is the sample number and the format is a complex number. I was told the real part is the I and the imaginary part is the Q. Are these samples received baseband I Q data? I am trying to determine the carrier frequency offset. I was trying to determine the frequency of the signal. I felt I could measure the phase difference between samples per time. However, I have the angles being only between pi/2 and -pi/2 when I do arctan(b/a). I assume I should unwrap the signal phase. In MATLAB there is the unwrap command (var = unwrap(phase)). But that does nothing to the values I received. I am unsure of how to proceed with my search for the carrier frequency offset. Any help?

Comment: without you even telling us what specific device that data comes from, how are we supposed what the data is? Also, this feels like a bit of a bad match for this website but really something to look up with the device documentation.

Comment: Oh I am sorry. The spectrum analyzer was Tektronix 306B USB and the bluetooth device I was studying was a EKO core bluetooth attachment for stethescopes. The .MAT file that I obtained from the device is obtained by using SignalVu software. The software used saves the data as a sequence of I and Q samples in as a complex number: a1 + ib1, a2 + ib2, a3 + ib3...just a 1 x n matrix. It can be easily separated to real and imaginary using real(Y) and imag(Y). I didnt see how that affected it, sorry

Comment: so, please edit your question to include that info. While you're editing that question, also make sure that you make clear, through structure and highlighting, what your actual question is.

Comment: Completely unknown without knowing the sample rate and any (down)modulation done between RF frequency and baseband IQ.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the phase progression I would recommend not using `atan()` in MATLAB to extract the phase angle.  Use the built-in function `angle()` to extract the phase from the complex samples properly accounting for the quadrant of the complex plane in which each sample appears.  This resulting phase can then be unwrapped.

`unwrappedPhaseRad = unwrap(angle(inputComplexSamples));`

where `unwrappedPhaseRad` is the unwrapped phase in radians and `inputComplexSamples` is a vector (1 dimensional array) of your complex input data samples.